# How to Update Online & Offline Status in database

Tags: php, mysqli

It's couple day's and I'm Working on it, I don't know how to create a simple online & offline Status for my users. Here is what i have done :

- First i created a field in users table `LAST_ACTIVITY (timestamp)`
  and `STATUS (String:Online or Offline)`
- Second,I wrote this code (i tried a lot of codes and this is the last
  one,Really confused):

Here is my code :

```
  $update_status = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET STATUS='online',LAST_ACTIVITY=NOW() WHERE Username='{$username_session}'");
  $check_status = mysqli_query($connection , "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='{$username_session}'");

   while($rr = mysqli_fetch_array($check_status)) 
     {   
      if (date("Y-m-d g:i:s") > $rr['LAST_ACTIVITY'] )   
       {
           $update_status = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET STATUS='offline',LAST_ACTIVITY=NOW() WHERE Username='{$username_session}'");
       }
     }
```

At this code `if (date("Y-m-d g:i:s") > $rr['LAST_ACTIVITY'] )` I tried to add 5 minutes on current time then to check if current time(5minutes more than `LAST_ACTIVITY TIMESTAMP`) then it should update `STATUS` to `Offline`,I tired this to add minutes:

```
$makeTime = mktime(0,0,0,date("g"),date("i")+5,date("s"));
$makeTime2 = date("g:i:s", $makeTime);
```

But didn't work, I hope you got what I mean. Please help me solve this, Explain very simple and clear for me.

Comment: are you running the first two queries as shown, just one after another?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: I'm Really confused please if you have any solution provide it then,i'll be greateful

Comment: to whom and whose status you want to show? I have a feeling that your code is intended to show his offline status to a user who is off line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more easy to work with a `timestamp` here. Just set the current timestamp for the current user as `LAST_ACTIVITY`. To do this, you need to change the column `LAST_ACTIVITY` to `INT(10)` in the database.

```
// current timestamp
$now = time();

// update current user
mysqli_query($connection, "
    UPDATE users
    SET STATUS = 'online', LAST_ACTIVITY = {$now}
    WHERE Username = '{$username_session}'");
```

Then just update all entries in the database, where the `LAST_ACTIVITY` is older than 5 minutes.

```
// 60 Seconds * 5 = 300
$older = time() - 300;

// set all older entries as offline
mysqli_query($connection, "
    UPDATE users
    SET STATUS = 'offline'
    WHERE LAST_ACTIVITY < {$older}");
```

Another way to reset the online status is to create an scheduled event directly in the database. But this not great for maintenance and clearance in the future. A `cron job` would be mutch nicer solution.

But just to be complete, here is a way letting the database update it on it's own (*untested*):

```
CREATE EVENT set_offline
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
  UPDATE users
  SET STATUS = 'offline'
  WHERE LAST_ACTIVITY < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 300;
```

Comment: it works fine,but there is one problem,as i see it's work with refresh,each refresh it will  query , it does not update last user status,because the page need to be refreshed...any other solution?

Comment: Yes, you will need to put the _offline part_ in some kind of cron job. So the script will run automatically in the background. Actually you're correct, the last user will stay online until some other go on this page. @Aqil

Comment: i dont know about cron job,anyway thanks for answer,i think i should be the last one lol, i will wait 24hour to see other's answers ,till now your answer is the best one

Comment: Simply said, a cron job is a scheduler on the server witch can execute scripts in different timings. So for exmple, it could call your script every one minute, so the status will be updated. You can find many, many articles about cron jobs on the web. But there is nothing you can just change in the script, so the status will be updated automatically. PHP only work on request, so without a request there is no action. @Aqil

Comment: I've added an example for an scheduled event in the database, which could update the status on it's own. It's not tested, but should work or at least give you an hint. Maybe this helps you. @Aqil

Comment: I've Reached question limit,please i have another question if possible for you contact me on my email aqilhex@gmail.com